# Error: Package tuple ('php-pecl-jsonc', 'x86_64', '0', '1.3.7', '1.el6.remi.5.6') could not be found in rpmdb

Tags: php, centos, upgrade, yum

I need to upgrade my PHP version from 7.1.26 to 7.2 due to symfony on my CentOS server but I got this error:

```
Error: Package tuple ('php-pecl-jsonc', 'x86_64', '0', '1.3.7', '1.el6.remi.5.6') could not be found in rpmdb
```

I did:

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
yum install php php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql php-ldap php-zip php-fileinfo --skip-broken
```

and got this:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Determining fastest mirrors
Could not get metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64 error was
14: problem making ssl connection
 * base: tux.rainside.sk
 * epel: mirror.vutbr.cz
 * extras: tux.rainside.sk
 * remi: rpms.remirepo.net
 * remi-php56: rpms.remirepo.net
 * remi-php71: rpms.remirepo.net
 * remi-php72: rpms.remirepo.net
 * remi-safe: rpms.remirepo.net
 * updates: tux.rainside.sk
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
WANdisco-git                                                                                                                                                 | 2.9 kB     00:00
WANdisco-git/primary_db                                                                                                                                      | 134 kB     00:00
base                                                                                                                                                         | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                                                                                                                       | 3.4 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                                                                                                                            |  29 kB     00:00
icinga-stable-release                                                                                                                                        | 2.5 kB     00:00
icinga-stable-release/primary_db                                                                                                                             | 309 kB     00:00
remi                                                                                                                                                         | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi/primary_db                                                                                                                                              | 2.3 MB     00:00
remi-php56                                                                                                                                                   | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-php56/primary_db                                                                                                                                        | 245 kB     00:00
remi-php71                                                                                                                                                   | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-php71/primary_db                                                                                                                                        | 212 kB     00:00
remi-php72                                                                                                                                                   | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-php72/primary_db                                                                                                                                        | 196 kB     00:00
remi-safe                                                                                                                                                    | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-safe/primary_db                                                                                                                                         | 1.2 MB     00:00
updates                                                                                                                                                      | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                                                                                                                           | 3.7 MB     00:00
webtatic                                                                                                                                                     | 2.4 kB     00:00
Package php-mysql-5.4.45-17.el6.remi.x86_64 is obsoleted by php-mysqlnd-7.1.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64 which is already installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:7.1.26-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php.x86_64 0:7.2.18-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libargon2.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-7.2.18-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:7.1.26-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:7.2.18-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:7.1.26-1.el6.remi will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.26-1.el6.remi for package: php-json-7.1.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64
Error: Package tuple ('php-pecl-jsonc', 'x86_64', '0', '1.3.7', '1.el6.remi.5.6') could not be found in rpmdb
```

Could somebody help me with this?

source for the upgrade: https://www.tecmint.com/install-php-7-in-centos-6/

Thank you.

Comment: As php is installed, try a simple "yum update". BTW, php-pecl-jsonc is PHP 5.x only , so don't need to be there (replaced by php-json)

Comment: you can also disable remi-php56 and remi-php71 as only remi-php72 is needed

Comment: I disabled remi-php56 and tried "yum update" but got the same error. I don't know why yum is trying to install php-pecl-jsonc as I don't need that any more and I don't even know what needs this dependency.

Comment: run a "yum check all", but looks like your rpmdb is corrupted

Comment: Also disable webtatic which create conflicts (a single provider avoid issue)

Comment: yum check all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
check ['all']

Comment: yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not get metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64 error was
14: problem making ssl connection
 * base: tux.rainside.sk
 * epel: mirror.vutbr.cz
 * extras: tux.rainside.sk
 * remi: rpms.remirepo.net
 * remi-php71: rpms.remirepo.net
 * remi-php72: rpms.remirepo.net
 * remi-safe: rpms.remirepo.net
 * updates: tux.rainside.sk
Error: Package tuple ('php-pecl-jsonc', 'x86_64', '0', '1.3.7', '1.el6.remi.5.6') could not be found in rpmdb